# Pasar variable de c# a javascript en asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Tengo esta variable en el `action` de la vista C#:

```
string blah = "this is a blah string";
```

Esto es lo que tengo en Javascript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var JavascriptBlah = '<%=blah%>';
  alert(JavascriptBlah);
</script>
```

Esa forma la vi en Internet pero no me funciona. No se si hay otra forma actualizada ya que donde lo tome fue publicado hacen 10 años.

Comment: Seria conveniente si puedes indicar cual es el objetivo de pasar la variable a javascript? la funcionalidad requerida. Porque pueden existir alternativas a esto para cada necesidad (escribir en la vista MVC, solicitar informacion por ajax a una API, o incluso renderizar HTML de una API, o estar escuchando mensajes/eventos con signalR en tiempo real, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a darle referencia de la página de microsoft donde explican sobre signal R. Signal R no solo le va a permitir comunicar c# con javascript sino que también le va a permitir tener una aplicación en tiempo real.Adjunto el enlace:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio.
Entonces por ejemplo usted declara un método en su servidor net core :

```
  public class ChatHub : Hub
        {
            public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
            }
        }
```

Y por medio de el método SendAsync() usted envia los datos que quiera y esos datos los va a recibir en sus scripts de javascript . En este caso sería algo parecido a esto:

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

Pero para poder hacer todo esto primero debe instalar signal R. En el link adjunto viene todo lo que necesita saber paso a paso.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas con .NET Core estas utilizando ASP.NET Core MVC, si estas con MVC tienes formas de pasar datos a la vista

- Vistas de ASP.NET Core MVC > Paso de datos a las vistas
  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#passing-data-to-views

Aquí depende de como estas desarrollando o tienes [un objeto de tus entidades para el modelo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (por ejemplo un objeto cliente, producto, etc.) o tienes algo como una variable que deberías utilizar ViewBag

Bueno, generalmente en los ejenplos se pasan modelos para visualizarlos en el HTML entonces veras algo asi

```
@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.Cliente

<h2>Cliente @Model.Nombre @Model.Apellido</h2>
<address>
    @Model.Calle @Model.Altura<br>
    @Model.Ciudad, @Model.EstadoProvincia, CP: @Model.CodigoPostal<br>
 </address>
```

Para pasar datos a Javascript es similar, o sea del modelo (tipado en un objeto o con viewbag) escribirlo en la vista .
Para visualizar en un ejemplo arme uno... (dale una mirada)

- [MVC] Pasar valor del modelo a javascript
  https://dotnetfiddle.net/QkpKVC

Mira allí la linea 66 de la vista (es solo un ejemplo, ya que solo tiene una vista que allí esta todo el HTML, sin layout de MVC)

```
$(function(){
     var clienteId = '@Model.ClienteId';
     var clienteNombre = '@Model.Nombre';
            
     openAlert(clienteId);
        
 });
```

Con todo lo hasta aqui podrias "escribir" o "enviar" variables, propiedades de objetos del modelo a la vista

**Recomendaciones**

- Recomendación  1: Si tiene pagina master/layout, deberias agregar una seccion "Scripts" (puedes colocar el nombre que quieras a las secciones)... Dale una mirada a [¿qué son las secciones en MVC?](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sections), que basicamente nos ayuda a organizar. En este caso que la seccion "Script" se renderice al final de nuestras HTML al renderizar asi no bloquean el armado del HTML en el browser (al final donde deberia estar todos los scripts js)
  Ejemplo, si tienes una seccion

  ```
     @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
  ```

En tus vistas podrías (o no, ya que no es requerido) renderizar la sección así

```
    @section Scripts {
      <script>
        $(function(){
           var clienteId = '@Model.ClienteId';
           var clienteNombre = '@Model.Nombre';
            
           openAlert(clienteId);
         });
       </script>
     }
```

- Recomendación 2: Ver si existe alguna otra alternativa de obtener información del servidor (no renderizando en la vista sino por ejemplo obteniendo de través de una API, o escuchando algún mensaje/evento como te comento con SignalR

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.